# Finding the Working Days Between two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to find the difference between two dates by excluding the weekends i.e Sunday and Saturday in SQL Server??

Comment: What did you already do to solve your problem?

Comment: Consider creating a calendar table keyed by date along with additional attributes for weekday, holiday, etc.  Joining to such a table will be more efficient and flexible than using date/time functions on the fly.  Search for "sql server calendar table".

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
select *,  datepart(dw,yourdate) as dayofweek where dayofweek between 1 and 5
```

0 sunday
1 monday
...
5 friday
6 sunday